# SQLite Database getting deleted in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hello everyone,

I have built a sample app which takes input from user and save it in a table in a database.I have created my own database for my app and saved data in it. Every thing seems to be fine. The other day, I started Eclipse IDE and started running my application. I was not able to see any data in my application.

When I see in file explorer(DDMS), there was no database ( my database, table, data in it every thing lost). I heard that SQLite database is persistent. I used general syntax for creating database and table. Please any one suggest me why this has happened.

This is my MainActivity.java,

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final android.content.Context Context = MainActivity.this;
public String ReadingMode = "";
public String Value = "";
public String DialogStatus = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    Button saveWaterReadingToDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveReading);
    saveWaterReadingToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final String TABLE_NAME = "WaterElectricity";
            String COLUMN_NAME_READING_ID = "_Id";
            String COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE = "ReadingMode";
            String COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME = "StartDateTime";
            String COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE = "ReadingValue";


            final SQLiteDatabase DB = Context.openOrCreateDatabase(
                    "WaterElectricityReadingDataBase.db",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);

            final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists "
                    + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_NAME_READING_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_READING_MODE + " text not null,"
                    + COLUMN_NAME_PASTDATETIME + " date not null, "
                    + "EndDateTime date not null, "
                    + COLUMN_NAME_READINGVALUE + " integer not null" + ");";

             DB.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
                         }
        }); 

       }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen all the time?

Comment: data folder in ddms will show file for emulator and rooted devices

Comment: yes. Everytime I start my eclipse , everything seems to be fresh. All my databases are being deleted.

Answer (score 2):

All databases may be deleted every time you restore/re-run your emulator.

Closing eclipse has **nothing** to do with your database deleting, as it's all saved in your emulators directory.

Your emulators database is actually stored on a piece of virtual memory. To see this (In windows) go to username/.android/avd and you will see all of your AVD's set up as directories (containing all files pertaining to that emulator)

### Make sure this is unchecked:

[image: Make sure this is unchecked]

### File Path with Files:

[image: File Path with Files]

### SD Card img file (containing the actual db)?:

---

**This is just me taking an educated guess on which file is the actual sdcard file. Someone feel free to correct me.**

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I checked the Launch Options of my emulator. That is unchecked. Though it is unchecked, my data is being erased. Any other options are to be set? What about in real phone? The same thing happens in phone also?   Please suggest.

Comment: Its fine if this deleting of data happens only with emulator and not in real phone.